# Why am I getting an "Access denied to 'localhost'" error?

Tags: java, mysql

I've been trying to log in to mysql, with a username of "root", and a password of "pass", and this is the stacktrace I get when I try to run a java program using a database:

```
Apr 12, 2014 4:51:41 PM carselectionui.CarSelectionUIWDB main
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at carselectionui.CarSelectionUIWDB.main(CarSelectionUIWDB.java:597)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at carselectionui.CarSelectionUIWDB.main(CarSelectionUIWDB.java:604)
```

The strange thing is, I was actually able to connect to the DB when I was working on the code a couple of weeks ago, but ever since I rebooted my computer, I'm getting the access denied error again. I tried using no password, thinking that the password reset on reboot, but I still get the same error. I get this error anytime I try to connect to the database, so I know that it's not the code that's the problem.

I'm using Windows 7, and these are my path values:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Go\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6;C/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin/mysql.exe;
C/Program Files (x86) /MySQL/Connector J 5.1.29/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar;
C:/Users/pnflift8191/;
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/Connector J 5.1.29/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar
```

Just realized that I have mysql-connector on there twice, but I know that's not the reason this isn't working, because it still didn't work before I accidentally added it on there again.

EDIT: I've also tried connecting through the command line and MYSQL workbench, and I still get an error.

Comment: if 'I've also tried connecting through the command line and MYSQL workbench, and I still get an error' means you get hat error there, too, then you should look whether you mysql service is running

Comment: @SirRotN If it wasn't running he would get a connection exception, not an access denial.

Comment: Either the username or password is wrong or that user isn't permitted to connect from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program as an administrator [right click the jar or whatever and run as admin]. If you are using eclipse as an IDE you should run eclipse with administrator privileges [same process].

If that still doesn't work, ensure that the username and password are correct.

Comment: Running as an admin can't change anything. He is connecting to MySQL all right, but it is rejecting the username/password. One of them is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I ended up solving this problem is to:
1: Stop the MySQL service
2: type: mysqld -skip--grant--tables in the command line
3: I'm able to start MySQL.

The only problem with this method is that this works for any username and password, but at least I can work on MySQL.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as you've noted this has a problem (and it's not a mere problem, leaving the database open, as you have, is truly idiotic)